# Javascript JQuery detect google form submission in iframe and activate conversion tracking google analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-analytics, conversion-tracking

I have a google form submitting answers to a google spreadsheet.
I have put this form in an IFRAME on our website.

Now I would like to add a script that detects when the Google form is submitted in this iframe. This should then activate a conversion pixel in google analytics.

I've been searching for this for a while now and cannot seem to find the right answer.

My google form containts 2 pages + 1 submit page
So I tried counting if the iframe detects 3 load times.
Instead of the alert I was thinking to redirect to a thank you page with the conversion pixel.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
count = 0;    
$('iframe').load(function(){
     count++;
     if(count == 3)
        alert("activate pixel");
});</script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe id="iframe" src="[LINK TO GOOGLE FORM]" width=100% height="1500" frameborder="0">
<iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post some code that shows what you have tried?

Comment: My google form containts 2 pages + 1 submit page
So I tried counting if the iframe detects 3 load times.
Instead of the alert I was thinking to redirect to a thank you page with the conversion pixel. 

<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
count = 0;    
$('iframe').load(function(){
     count++;
     if(count == 3)
        alert("activate pixel");
});</script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe id="iframe" src="[LINK TO GOOGLE FORM]" width=100% height="1500" frameborder="0">
<iframe>
</body>
</html>

Comment: thanks man this really helped me to make an action after submitting a google form from an iframe!